# \begin{array}{ccc:ccc} : No error, but just not working properly

Tags: arrays, line, vertical

I would like to add a vertical dashed line between the third and fourth column. The following is my code.
This code is working well with my thesis template, but a vertical dashed line is not appearing in my manuscript template. No error, but just no vertical line.
Document class is 'article'.

```
\begin{align*}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc:ccc}
a_{11} b_{11} & a_{11} b_{12} & a_{11} b_{13} & a_{12} b_{11} & a_{12} b_{12} & a_{12} b_{13} \\
a_{11} b_{21} & a_{11} b_{22} & a_{11} b_{23} & a_{12} b_{21} & a_{12} b_{22} & a_{12} b_{23} \\
a_{11} b_{31} & a_{11} b_{32} & a_{11} b_{33} & a_{12} b_{31} & a_{12} b_{32} & a_{12} b_{33} \\
\hdashline [2pt/2pt]
a_{21} b_{11} & a_{21} b_{12} & a_{21} b_{13} & a_{22} b_{11} & a_{22} b_{12} & a_{22} b_{13} \\
a_{21} b_{21} & a_{21} b_{22} & a_{21} b_{23} & a_{22} b_{21} & a_{22} b_{22} & a_{22} b_{23} \\
a_{21} b_{31} & a_{21} b_{32} & a_{21} b_{33} & a_{22} b_{31} & a_{22} b_{32} & a_{22} b_{33}
\end{array}
\right] 
\end{align*}
```

And there are the list of packages that I am currently using now. (Order is preserved.)

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}
```

What I am thinking is:

1. {ccc:ccc} is not functioning right. But no error.
2. Considering that this code works fine with my thesis template, one of the packages might be interrupping, while I do not know what that is.

I was suffering from this problem for an entire day! Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated and welcomed!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your code misses a `\right]`.

Comment: Hi Bernard. Thank you for noticing this. I have \right] in my code, indeed. I modified this post just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Output]It seems to work for me — though note Bernard's comment; you have missed a `\right]` .

**Edit:**

Using the template linked:

[image: TemplateOutput]

Have you tried compiling with a non-dashed line? There's nothing wrong with the code you used, and the packages you're using aren't mucking it up. Maybe try switching compilers?

Comment: Hi Infiaria. I am having the same problem. It perfectly is working in my thesis template. However, not in the different template. Currently I am using a manuscript template obtained from PLOS Computational Biology, but somehow the vertical line is not shown without any error!

Comment: @rudgus51998 I did read your post, yes. But I don't think I can help you here, since I can't seem to reproduce it (using the code you gave). It might help if you link to the template.

Comment: Thank you for your help! http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/s/latex <- From here, you can download the exactly same template that I am using now. You might need to add some packages (listed above in the original post) such as 'arydshln' by yourself though. I sincerely appreciate your help!!

Comment: @rudgus51998 Unfortunately, I still can't seem to reproduce what you're saying. I've edited my post so you can see what I'm on about.

Comment: Oh my god! This is super weird. I sincerely appreciate it!! I will try to use different complier, then.

Comment: I have one more question. I am using texstudio; what program are you using for latex?

Comment: @rudgus51998 I'm using Texmaker using PdfLaTeX and MiKteX.